# Alternatives to Faux column on a single centered colunmn

Tags: html, css

I am working on a centered 2-column layout. Both halves of the centered column stretch equally because I have a footer beneath it. How can I make the center column - *at its shortest* -  no shorter than the browser?

What are alternatives (using CSS only if possible) to the faux column technique?

Code welcome.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to be clear - the problem isn't inner DIVs extending beyond the outer DIV (the clear on the footer should take care of that unless there's something weird) - and instead you're looking for the outer DIV to take up the whole viewport size, with its footer always at the bottom of the viewport?

If so, what you're most likely looking for is a sticky footer.  Check out [this solution here](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/), it's quite simple and relatively elegant (at least given that this isn't a very easy problem).  It uses a 100% height and negative bottom margin on the wrapper, the negative bottom margin matching the height of the footer.

Comment: 'sactly what I'm looking for. You got it right. +1 for now, check if it works.

Comment: I it changed my design of the site, but thanks. Check for you and I guess I will get around to testing it eventually.